# angular cli including additional static resources during live reload?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using the latest version of the Angular CLI. I have some mock http calls that are referencing local json '../app/myfile.json' etc. In order to stop getting 404's during the reload process do I have to add them somewhere? I've tried adjusting the paths in .angular-cli.json but keep getting 404 errors.

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.4
node: 6.9.4
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.0.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
```

I have tried to modify the .angular-cli.json to add the folder I want to include.

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "mocks"
      ],
```

when I reload i get: http://localhost:4200/app/mocks/myfile.json (404 not found)

Any help is appreciated.

Jimi

Comment: So, what did you try doing, where did you try placing the files, what code are you executing, and what error do you get?

Comment: Hi There, I have added some details around the question. Essentially I have tried to modify the .angular-cli.json to include the folders that I need but this is not making any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the path of the JSON file to be `/app/mocks/myfile.json`, then the file location in the project should be `src/app/mocks/myfile.json`, and the assets configuration should be

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "app/mocks"
  ],
```

[The documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration) provides more details.